# Prevent the generation process and execute

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio, Keys like [F5], [CRTL+F5], [F10], [F11] will generate and execute your code.
So any fat finger [F12], or any "reflexe" [F11] to enter the function definition, will excecute the code. Or a F5 in the Release mode instead of Debug.

Is there any Pannic Stop button to prevent your code for executing or to stop the generation process?

Or a way to prevent unexpected execution by having a prompt or something?

Comment: I just removed the AC on my Cisco switch twice in a row, to prevent execution.

Comment: How about not building world-ending programs? Pressing F11 just enters step-by-step execution, so it’s entirely harmless...?

Comment: @DanielB, Yes harmless, I guess the heart attack and the switch unplug were unnecessary. Still a F5 on release mode instead of debug mode could be frightening. So maybe the question still stand for this one.